# Cell validation in datagrid WPF based on cell values in other rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to create a simple time sheet application where in user can have different roles and based on the role he can update and view the time sheet. To update the time sheet I have implemented a **datagrid** which contains the date and a **time from** and **time to** in format of *"HH:mm"*.
 What I want is to validate cells time from and time to so the time interval is not already in the data grid , for example if a task has the work time from 2 PM to 5 PM and user want to insert a new task with the work time 4 PM to 6 PM the validation should fail.
 Till now I have implemented class **ValidationRule** but if I use it for row validation then I can not get the values of the new row and if I use it for cell I can not get the **ItemSource** of the **datagrid**.
Also thinked to use **INotifyDataErrorInfo** but also I don't know how to reach the **ItemSource** of the **datagrid**.

Actual implementation:
`View:`

```
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="All" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList , Mode=TwoWay}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          RowHeaderWidth="15" 
          CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
          CanUserResizeRows="False"
          Margin="10 20 10 10">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="User Id" Binding="{Binding UserId}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date , StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy\}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time from">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <Binding Path="TimeFrom" StringFormat="HH:mm">
                    <Binding.ValidationRules>
                        <validation:TimeIntervalValidation/>
                    </Binding.ValidationRules>
                </Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time to" Binding="{Binding TimeTo , StringFormat=\{0:HH:mm\}}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Task" Binding="{Binding Task}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="3*" Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

ViewModels:

```
public class TimesheetViewModel:BindableBase
{
    private List<TimeSheet> _dataList;

    public List<TimeSheet> DataList
    {
        get => _dataList;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _dataList, value);
        }
    }
}

public class TimeSheet : BindableBase
{
    private DateTime _date,_timeFrom,_timeTo;
    private string _task, _description;
    private int _id, _userId;

    public int Id
    {
        get => _id;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _id, value);
        }
    }
    public int UserId
    {
        get => _userId;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _userId, value);
        }
    }
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get => _date;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _date, value);
        }
    }
    public DateTime TimeFrom
    {
        get => _timeFrom;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _timeFrom, value);
        }
    }
    public DateTime TimeTo
    {
        get => _timeTo;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _timeTo, value);
        }
    }
    public String Task
    {
        get => _task;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _task, value);
        }
    }
    public String Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _description, value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: BindableBase is a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`** 
Forgot to add `TimeIntervalValidation` class

```
 public class TimeIntervalValidation:ValidationRule
{

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {

        // implementation

        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }

}
```

TimeSheet model generated by EF :

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Timesheet
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime TimeFrom { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime TimeTo { get; set; }
        public string Task { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
     }
    }
```

Comment: You could create a custom collection that hooks up an event handler to the `PropertyChanged` event of all items in it and then performs the validation when a property of any of the items changes.

Comment: Please show what you tried. You can bind to properties of the DataContext of the DataGrid from inside a cell template: `{Binding DataContext.SomeCollectionBoundToItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}`. Do you have a viewmodel? If not, you could just bind directly to the ItemsSource property of the DataGrid: `{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}`

Comment: @mm8 I will try your tip  and yes I do have  a viewmodel

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have posted some code , take a look if you please

Comment: [This article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31422.wpf-passing-a-data-bound-value-to-a-validation-rule.aspx) discusses a way to get a binding onto a ValidationRule. It gets a bit involved. Another approach might be to use ObservableCollection rather than List for `DataList` (if you call every collection `DataList`, how do you tell them apart?), and handle its CollectionChanged event to add PropertyChanged handlers to every timesheet row (why is everything named timesheet?) that gets added, then do as mm8 suggests for validation.

Comment: The purpose is to learn WPF and get used with datagrid so I haven't bothered much with names

Comment: If you're learning MVVM, I'd suggest learning the difference between a model and a viewmodel.

Comment: @EdPlunkett So in fact they are both ViewModels , what would be the right implementation? having lets call a TimeSheetModel which would implement INotifyPropertyChanged and one more ViewModel class which would be the layer between TimeSheetModel and View?

Comment: @GabrielCostin Models don't implement INPC. The "model" in MVVM is a basic representation of the data with bare CLR properties: `public int ID { get; set; }`, generally serializable. For trivial programs, you don't necessarily have to bother writing a model. If you were getting your timesheets from a database via a web service, in a nontrivial application, you'd have a model for TimeSheet and another for TimeSheetRow, and you'd have viewmodels for both of those as well. The viewmodels would either clone or wrap the properties with INPC properties.

Comment: viewmodel and model aren't two levels in your data model hierarchy. They're two roughly parallel hierarchies. What if TimeSheetRow has a collection property of its own? What if your whole hierarchy is Company -> Employees -> TimeSheet -> TimeSheetRow? A viewmodel also adds commands and other UI-related stuff that the data layer shouldn't worry about.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am using EF so I have a class that is a model coresponding to each table in database, so you saying that I should create models for example TimeSheetRow with those properties I need , and also create a coresponding ViewModel where I should clone properties of the TimeSheetRow and implement INPC ? what if I need a collection of TimeSheetRow ? I still need INPC on each property  so the UI get updated

Comment: @EdPlunkett And about the sentence "viewmodel also adds commands and other UI-related stuff that the data layer shouldn't worry about " - in the above example I have created a class TimeSheet(which I wanted to be some kind of a model) and it only implements INPC, nothing else. In ViewModel I also create commands and other stuff like you said but I deleted them for increasing readability. If a model has only plain properties , then in ViewModel how can I have a collection of a model that is not implementing INPC but UI still get updated ?

Comment: @GabrielCostin If you’re using EF, EF is your model. If I recall correctly, EF classes implement INPC as well. you can easily check that in the generated source files in your project. As for your last sentence, many viewmodel classes. Many many. ViewmodelA can have collection of ViewmodelB. ViewmodelB can have collection of ViewmodelC and so on down. But you can bind a collection of an EF class right to a DataGrid.

Comment: @EdPlunkett EF classes does not have INPC implemented, I can show you the code generated for same class TimeSheet that it only has a foreign key as a virtual property and plain properties

Comment: @mm8 Could you please lead me to a similar implementation ?

Comment: @GabrielCostin: This question has been closed so I can't post an answer. If you ask a new question and try to be a bit more specific abour your issue, I'll do my best to try to help you.

Comment: @mm8 Ok could you then try to explain here? How to perform validation ? And also I would like to perform validation only on the changed cell not on the entire cells , I am new to WPF and till now I used validation along with DataAnnotations and implementing ValidationRule class, how can I validate a property  A based on a collection of items where A is a property of that item?

Comment: @GabrielCostin Interesting. Our EF classes inherit ultimately from [System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.StructuralObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.dataclasses.structuralobject?view=netframework-4.8), which does implement INPC, and their properties raise PropertyChanged. So there must be an option in there somewhere to make that happen. I don't personally know EF at all well, though.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I will add at the bottom of question the template of that class auto generated by EF

Comment: @GabrielCostin OK, so that's a nice basic model class for a TimeSheetRow. A row, not the whole timesheet. The 3.2 seconds you saved on naming will cost you hours of self-induced confusion. A developer *could* just toss a collection of those in a grid, for example if it's a read-only grid, or if each cell's value and validation and styling is entirely independent of all the others. However, in your case, you need change notifications on at least one property. You've got two options:

Comment: @GabrielCostin 1) Rename that to TimeSheetRow and write a TimeSheetRowViewModel which *wraps* a private instance of TimeSheetRow, and uses that for private backing fields: `public String Task { get { return _timeSheetRow.Task; } set { SetProperty(_timeSheetRow.Task, value); } }`. Or 2) do the exact same thing, but have your own private backing fields. Either way, `TimeSheetRowViewModel` has a constructor that takes a `TimeSheetRow` to initialize itself from, and give it a method that initializes and returns a `TimeSheetRow` instance which reflects any edits the user made.

Comment: @GabrielCostin Either way, the parent `TimeSheetViewModel` has a collection of `TimeSheetRowViewModel`, and `TimeSheetViewModel` is responsible for populating that collection based on the `TimeSheetRow` objects it gets from EF. There should be a parent viewmodel that owns the current `TimeSheetViewModel`, or maybe a collection of `TimeSheetViewModel`. A full HR application would have a `TimeSheetManagerViewModel` or something that had a collection of `TimeSheetViewModel`, a currently selected `TimeSheetViewModel`, and commands to delete and save current `TimeSheetViewModel` and create new ones

Comment: @GabrielCostin And `TimeSheetManagerViewModel` would be one child viewmodel belonging to the `MainViewModel`. Maybe `MainViewModel` would also have a `BenefitsViewModel` child with its own tree of children a few levels deep. You get the general idea.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes I saw the implementation `1` somewhere while I was googling and will use it from now on. Regarding to my main topic of this question could you give me any hint ? I have changed to `ObservableCollection`  but I do not know where exactly to implement validatators , implement  in CollectionChanged event or trying to create a custom validator that inherits ValidatorsRule class and trying to bind the ItemSource of datagrid as an argument to that validator in XAML?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198942/discussion-between-gabriel-costin-and-ed-plunkett).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ValidationStep property of the Validationrule to ValidationStep.UpdatedValue (e.g. in XAML or the constructor) to have the Validate function be called with the updated Values.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validationstep?view=windowsdesktop-8.0

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
  <local:TimeIntervalValidation ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"/>
</DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

(from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-implement-validation-with-the-datagrid-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

or in visual basic:

```
   Public Class TimeIntervalValidation
      Inherits ValidationRule

      Sub New()
         Me.ValidationStep = ValidationStep.UpdatedValue

      End Sub

      Public Overrides Function Validate(value As Object, cultureInfo As CultureInfo) As ValidationResult

         Dim drvRow As DataRowView = CType(CType(value, BindingGroup).Items(0), DataRowView)
         If CType(drvRow.Row.Item("TimeFrom"), Date) < Now Then
            Return ValidationResult.ValidResult
         Else
            Return New ValidationResult(False, "TimeFrom must be in the future.")
         End If
      End Function
   End Class
```